# Law of large numbers without iid assumption

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

As this is just a reference request, I hope I can get away with being brief. I am simply wondering about generalizations of the classical strong law of large numbers, which states that 
$$n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \to EX$$
almost surely whenever $(X_n)$ is an iid sequence of integrable random variables.

> What can we say about convergence of sample mean to expected value *without* the iid assumption? In other words, how can we weaken the assumption of iid and still get the desired convergence?

Comment: Obviously nothing. Take $X$ to be uniform on $(0,1)$ and $X_i = X$ for all $i$ (so that they all have same value).

Comment: Nothing in general since there are counterexamples that are far from anything resembling a LLN. However there are certainly versions under weaker assumptions (speaking of which, in your statement, you forgot to include the requirement that the $X_n$ be integrable). There are a lot of results you'll see in time series statistics for sequences with well-behaved autocorrelation. I don't have a definitive source/theorem, but you can find stuff if you dig a little. e.g. here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2409/strong-law-of-large-numbers-for-weakly-dependent-random-variables

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen What I mean to ask is what weaker assumptions secure convergence. I've edited a bit.

Answer (score 7):

One can relax the independent identically distributed assumption in the following ways.

1. Assume that the sequence $\left(X_i\right)_{i\geqslant 0}$ is strictly stationary, that is, for all $N$, the vectors $\left(X_i\right)_{i=1}^n$ has the same distribution as $\left(X_{i+1}\right)_{i=1}^n$. This implies in particular that $X_i$ has the same distribution as $X_1$ for all $i$. Ergodic theorem tells that if $X_1$ is integrable, then $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i/n\to \mathbb E\left[X_1\mid\mathcal I\right]$ almost surely, where $\mathcal I$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of invariant sets: we represent $(X_i)_{i\geqslant 0}$ as $(f\circ T^i)_{i\geqslant 0}$ where $T$ is measure preserving and $\mathcal I=\{A\mid T^{-1}A=A\}$.
2. An other way to relax the i.i.d. assumption is to work with martingales. In the case of identically distributed case (which is less restrictive than strict stationarity) martingale differences, one needs the assumption of integrability of $\left\lvert X_1\right\rvert\log\left(1+\left\lvert X_1\right\rvert\right) $ (see [this paper by J. Elton](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1176994414)).
3. Some other useful results on pairwise dependent random variables can be found in [this paper by V. Korchevsky](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.02234.pdf) and the references therein.

Comment: (a) Strict stationary is usually defined by requiring that for any $t_1,\ldots,t_n$ the distributions of $(X_{t_1+h}\  \ldots\ X_{t_n+h})'$ and $(X_{t_1}\ \ldots\  X_{t_n})'$ are the same for any $h$. Is this equivalent to the definition in your answer? (b) I don't think the statement holds for any strictly stationary sequence. For any strictly stationary sequence, we have that the sample mean converges almost surely to a random variable that has the same mean (see Theorem 9.5.4 of Karlin and Taylor (1975)). If the sequence is also ergodic, the limit is a constant equal to the expected value.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb (a) Yes it is equivalent: in one direction, take $t_i=i$; for the other use the definition in my answer with $n'=t_n$ instead of $n$. (b) Yes I forgot ergodicity.

Answer (score 5):

You can think of two well known generalizations.
You can weaken the assumption "identically distributed". If for instance $(X_1, X_2, ...)$ are independent and that $X_n \rightarrow_{n \rightarrow \infty} \nu$ in law, then it should not be difficult (assuming the $X_i$'s and $\nu$ to be $L^1$) to prove that:
$$a.s. \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n{X_i} \rightarrow_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int_0^\infty{x \nu(dx) } $$

You can also leverage the independence assumption. For example in the context of Markov Chains or more generally of stochastic processes, the [Birkhoff ergodic theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ergodic_theory#Probabilistic_formulation:_Birkhoff%E2%80%93Khinchin_theorem) (when it applies) gives a strong law of large numbers for strongly correlated random variables.